# RHEL + backup huge partition over network to local folder

Tags: ssh, rhel, rsync, backup, tar

We want to perform backup of `/DB_TABLES` from remote server to our local `/bck`

```
ssh root@main_server "tar cfz - /DB_TABLES" |tar xz -C /bck
```

Since `/DB_TABLES` partition on remote server is `1.4T`, we want to be sure that the below approach is the right way to backup a huge partition to local folder

The local folder that mounted to `/bck` is from disk with 2T.

Comment: `tar cfz` will create an archive named `z` (and the presence of the dash might cause a syntax error). Use `tar czf -` instead. You also need the `f -` option on the extracting tar. One caveat is the handling of [sparse files](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/sparse.html), in case you have any in /DB_TABLES. Most importantly, though, why don't you try it with a small directory first, and why don't you use a tool like `rsync`?

Comment: if you can please show me the rsync approach

Comment: Off the cuff: `rsync root@main_server:/DB_TABLES /bck`. If you don't want the DB_TABLES directory below /bck, add a slash after DB_TABLES. There are plenty of options for performance improvement and other features which may or may not be useful in your particular case, and plenty of tutorials on the internet.

Comment: I try it but we get skipping directory DB_TABLES

Comment: You probably have to add the `-r` flag (recursive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## it's complicated

**tar**

```
ssh root@main_server "tar czf - /DB_TABLES" |tar xzf - -C /bck
```

(note `z` before `f` as pointed out in comment, along with `f -` in extracting `tar`)

Will transfer files from remote `main_server` to local `/bck` directory, since `/DB_TABLES` is not small, some files might have changed by the time transfert is done, and as a result `/bck` might not be coherent.

**rsync**

```
rsync --archive --verbose --relative --delete root@main_server:/DB_TABLES/ /bck
```

Is slightly better, `rsync` will gather file in both side, then transfer new or changed files. The first time `rsync` will transfert all files. after, hopefully, smaller volume will get transfered; however if file are changed in `/DB_TABLES` after gathering phase, they will be missed (e.g. not transfered).

If you have many small files, you might run in parallel (1)

```
rsync --archive --verbose --relative --delete root@main_server:/DB_TABLES/dir1/ /bck
rsync --archive --verbose --relative --delete root@main_server:/DB_TABLES/dir2/ /bck
(...)
```

(1) proper syntax not garanteed.

**database**

You have to make/be sure files in `/DB_TABLES` are not changed during transfert (either `ssh+tar` or `rsync`), if this can be achieved (by stopping database for instance), then either solution will work (`rsync` might be faster on long run).

You might want to calibrate how long `rsync` took to know how long to stop/hang database.

If database can't be stopped, use remote syncing mecanism, if provided (log shipping, slave base).

**drill**

A costly but effective solution is to try to actually recover data (e.g. build a local replica and search for latest inserted record). This will involve many ressource and many people, might also include one or more actual stop of production database. Ideally this test should be perfom once a year/quarter.

Answer (score -1):

If you have enough space (in the remote server), you can made an archive first by something (for example x, creating something like a mycopy.x, launched by ssh), then transfer locally with rsync the mycopy.x
If fact with some archivers you can even use --append, which reduce the traffic (for multiple runs, ex. daily) of about 2/3 orders of magnitude (~100x/1000x faster), search by yourself which ones.
With ssh-password login (adjust the paths!) here a snippet

```
ssh myuser@myserver.com "/bin/x a /tmp/mycopy.x /DB_TABLES"
```

or with RSA key (in this example on default port 22)

```
/bin/ssh -p 22 -i /root/mysshkey myuser@myserver.com /bin/x a /tmp/mycopy.x /DB_TABLES
```

With ancient/ordinary archivers (tar, 7z, zip, rar etc) you need to transfer all the data, everytime (or, at least, do a full-check), maintaining only one copy of your data, with something like this (no key in this example, but password-entered login).

```
rsync -avr root@yourserver.com:/tmp/mycopy.x /temporaneo/dedup/mylocal
```

Or this (with RSA key, over standard port-22)

```
/bin/rsync -I -vv   --omit-dir-times --no-owner --no-perms --partial --progress -e "/bin/ssh -p 22 -i /root/mysshkey"  -rlt  --delete "myuser@myserver.com:/tmp/mycopy.x" "/temporaneo/dedup/mylocal"
```

If you use a zfs filesystem you can make a snapshot, then a replica (zfs-over-ssh), but I'm afraid that's not your case.

**EDIT/2: To avoid any kind of problems, even if I do not understand what they may be, I do not indicate which software is suitable for this case (WAN transfer of big database backup).

If anyone knows a software that can do this things please let me know.

There are thousands of opensource projects, of course I can't say to know them all.**

Comment: All well and good, but note one *“must disclose affiliation in answers”*: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/promotion

Comment: @FrancoCorbelli the main concern here is the github/fcorbelli link -- whether it is related to you or not. Simply claim (or disclaim!) affiliation with it; something along the lines of "I found this Github site, unrelated to me" or "I forked the original software and put it into my Github page here".  Thank you!

Comment: I understand your point of view, even if the link to GitHub is present in my profile. Therefore I have edited the answer indicating a generic X archiver which, however, will take (on multiple operations) about 1000x more time. If, by any chance, you know of another software that can do the same, please report. There is always something to learn. For greater security, I also delete the link from my profile. Since the username is the same as sourceforge and github (my name and surname) better if I delete this account at all?

Comment: Just for safety I delete the link at the original software (the entire comment, cannot edit, sorry). In fact I could be mentioned in it, and therefore it is better not to risk anything.

Comment: That’s rather unfortunate. It’s fine to write an answer using your tool, as long as you mention that you’re the author (or current maintainer, or whatever). Your original answer was much more useful; the only change required was to mention that it’s your tool.

Comment: In fact it is NOT. It's just a fork with some "bells and whistles", and in my profile I always put the github link, so I didn't think someone could fear some earning of something (??) with an opensource fork. There is even a Wikipedia page (no, not mine!). If you look @ the readme you will read "Who did that? One of the world's leading scientists in compression. No, not me, but this guy (LINK)" However it's not a big deal

Comment: I know you’re not the original author, but you are the maintainer of the fork you were presenting initially. This is not about whether you’re selling anything; it’s just about mentioning (briefly) that you are involved with the project you’re linking to.

Comment: Incidentally, I maintain the `zpaq` package in Debian, I’ll take a look at the improvements you’ve made since it might be worth using your fork instead!

Comment: If you know mr. Matt or write on encode.su we can continue here, I have the same nickname (as before I changed here), initial and surname.